# how can I remove the blur in screenshots?

Tags: ios, uiimage, screenshot

I have been testing how to post screenshot images to Facebook. All the images I've taken have a little blur. How can I remove the blur in the screenshots? Below is the method that takes the image.

```
-(UIImage*)takeASnapshot
{
   UIView *glView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];

   if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(glView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
   else
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(glView.bounds.size);

   [glView drawViewHierarchyInRect:glView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

   UIImage *screenShot ;
   screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenShot, 0.60);
   screenShot = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return screenShot;
}
```

Comment: Why do you lower or compress the quality to 0.60?

Comment: I changed it to 1.0 but there was still no improvement. The image quality didn't change

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code but the image taken was just white. What could be wrong?